# SQLAlchemy update() accepts only manually written JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I have problem with update-ing single row from my html form (I'm using Flask framework with SQLAlchemy, Python 3.4). I would like to pass my data as JSON to SQLAlchemy's update method()

This works for me:

```
db_session.query(Model_tbl_name).filter_by(id=Model_tbl_id).update({"title_hr":request.form['title_hr'],"text_hr":request.form['text_hr']})
```

There you can see data is added as JSON array in update() method. That works perfectly.

But when I try manually to add the JSON content, it does not work:

```
db_session.query(Model_tbl_name).filter_by(id=Model_tbl_id).update(str(json.dumps(new_request_form, ensure_ascii=False)))
```

I checked the passed data in json.dumps() and it is well formed JSON. 
It looks like this when i print it:

```
{"categories_id": "", "front_page": "ne", "price": "0.00", "sifra": "jghj", "title_hr": "ghjhg55573err", "video_title_hr": "ghjhgj", "video_url": ""}
```

What could be the problem? Why SQLAlchemy doesen't allow to add this data programatically?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `dict` to `update`, not `str`. To fix it, replace `json.dumps` with `json.loads`.

```
db_session.query(Model_tbl_name).filter_by(id=Model_tbl_id).update(json.loads(new_request_form))
```

Comment: I tried that also but no help. Later I tried with str() wrapper but no use with it also.

I just do not understand why SQLAlchemy doesen't allow this?

Comment: It worked! I had to do this before json.loads(): new_request_form = json.dumps(new_request_form, ensure_ascii=False). Thank you Yossi very much!

Comment: @DarioBB, `dumps` reverses the operation of `loads`. If you need both  for your code to work, you can probably eliminate them altogether and pass the parameter as is `.update(new_request_form)`.